# 2D array zeroing C++ style

Tags: c++, array

I have a valid code in C-style

```
int arr[10][10] = {0}; // all elements of array are 0
```

What is the optimal way to do the same for C++ style array?

**My idea is**

```
#include <array>

std::array<std::array<int, 10>, 10> arr = {0}; // is it correct?
```

Comment: This appears to be a general "best-practice" question, rather than a review of an existing function or program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel this question is more suited for stack overflow, but I'll answer it anyway. In c++ the preferred way to do this is:

```
std::array<std::array<int, 10>, 10> arr = {}; // Without the 0
```

Also remember that `static` variables are zero-initialised anyway, so you wouldn't need to do that.

Because this is code review, I would suggest using a `typedef` to replace `std::array<std::array<int, 10>, 10>` to make your code more readable.

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, `using` is much more powerful than `typedef` and more modern-c++ ish and one should preferably use it rather than `typedef`. It supports type aliasing templates and all other cool stuff, which is why it is preferable to use. ( Though never use `using namespace ...;`)

Comment: I would suggest to use `using` instead of `typedef` as we want to use modern c++ practices.

Comment: @AndreasBrunnet Yes you are totally right. Will edit the answer.